# javascript catching errors, null

Tags: javascript

When using the following syntax, would the output in console be `out` ?

I am making sure that I'm catching errors in callbacks and responding properly.

```
var err = null;

if (err) {
    console.log ("in");
} else {
    console.log ("out");
}
```

Comment: yes, null is "falsey"

Comment: `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0` etc.. will print `out`

Comment: Why haven't you simply tried it out?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something that could have easily been answered in 2 seconds by the poster trying it out himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your value is one of the following:

- 0
- null
- ""
- false
- undefined
- NaN

the object is set to false. For any other value it is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Using either your browser's JavaScript console or a site like http://repl.it/ can be really helpful to test logical expressions. One thing you can always do if you're not sure about the truthiness of an expression (doesn't matter as much for a simple case like this, but can be especially helpful when debugging with watch expressions or conditional breakpoints) is cast it to boolean (true/false) by using the `!` operator twice. For example:

- `!!null === false // true`
- `!!0 === false // true`
- `!![] === true // true`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes. But you can test it yourself by running in the browser.